# Slicing a sliced reference

Tags: go, slice

I'm taking the tour on Golang site, and I'm trying to digest one of the examples. It is unclear how it works:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    printSlice(s)

    // Slice the slice to give it zero length.
    s = s[:0]
    printSlice(s)

    // Extend its length.
    s = s[:4]
    printSlice(s)

    // Drop its first two values.
    s = s[2:]
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

The output is:

```
len=6 cap=6 [2 3 5 7 11 13]
len=0 cap=6 []
len=4 cap=6 [2 3 5 7]
len=2 cap=4 [5 7]
```

After the first slice, `s = s[:0]` the slice length is 0. Then there is another slicing of `s = s[:4]`. Although the length is 0, this seems to work. *But how this happens*? Shouldn't the underlaying array be in accessible from `s`?

What confuses me more is, the next time we slice it, `s = s[2:]` we slice the old value of s (which is 4 elements) and not the *original array*.

Can someone shed some lights what is the difference between the two cases?

Comment: There is an in-depth blog post on the official golang blog about the topic of slices [here](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals), which might interest you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Leon* addressed me to the Go's blog post, where they address exactly my question.

This is the snippet which helped me better understanding this concept:

> A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment).
>
> *A slice cannot be grown beyond its capacity.* Attempting to do so will cause a runtime panic, just as when indexing outside the bounds of a slice or array. **Similarly, slices cannot be re-sliced below zero to access earlier elements in the array.**

Slices can be extended if the array has more elements in it, but it can not access elements below 0 of the slice. *It's a **window** to the underlaying array*. The [blog post](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) explains it in more depth.

Answer (score 5):

A slice is basically a pointer to memory with some additional information:

1) the number of elements currently used and

2) the capacity, i.e. the remaining length it can occupy.

At the start we create a slice with 6 integers, this makes go create the underlying int array with a total size of 6 as well.

```
here is your memory locations with addresses (content does not matter here)
 *  *  *  *  *  *
[0][1][2][3][4][5]
 ^
 s points to the start of the memory
len(s) = 6
cap(s) = 6
```

Next we say: make this slice's `len` be 0, this is the `s = s[:0]` which takes a sub-slice of `s` at position 0 with length 0. Note that `s[0:0]` is the same, you can omit the first 0.

```
[0][1][2][3][4][5]
 ^
 s still points to the start of the memory
len(s) = 0
cap(s) = 6
```

Since the capacity is still the same, we might as well make the length 4 by saying `s = s[:4]`.

```
 *  *  *  *
[0][1][2][3][4][5]
 ^
 s still points to the start of the memory
len(s) = 4
cap(s) = 6
```

Then we take a sub-slice that does not start at the beginning of the memory by doing `s = s[2:]`.

```
       *  *
[0][1][2][3][4][5]
       ^
       s now points to the original address plus two!
len(s) = 2
cap(s) = 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I understand this part. The blogpost Leon refers to has the answer to my question